# Duplicate current quote with new ID on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, quote

Is there a way to somehow take the existing quote and create a new one identical to it but with a new ID?

This is what I currently have:

Updated following suggestions from @Vishwas:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

class ShareCart extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultFactory;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $quoteFactory;
    protected $transportBuilder;
    protected $stateInterface;
    protected $cart;
    protected $productFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ResultFactory $resultFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        QuoteRepository $quoteFactory,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StateInterface $stateInterface,
        Cart $cart,
        ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->stateInterface = $stateInterface;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        try
        {
            $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();

            $id = $this->cart->getQuote()->getId();

            if ($id > 0) {
                $quote = $this->quoteFactory->get($id);
                $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    $productId = $item->getProductId();
                    $_product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);

                    $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());

                    $info = $options['info_buyRequest'];
                    $request1 = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
                    $request1->setData($info);

                    $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $request1);
                }
                $this->cart->save();

                // Retrieve form data
                $email   = $post['basketshare-email'];
                $message = $post['basketshare-message'];

                $from_name = "";
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
    }
}
```

}

UPDATE:

```
    $this->cart->addProduct($product, $request);

}

// save the updated cart items then re-attach the cart to the original quote
$this->cart->save();
$this->cart->setQuote($quote);
$this->checkoutSession->setQuoteId($quote->getId());
$this->cart->save();
```

I think there is something I'm not doing right here but I'm struggling to find any help on Google at the moment :)

Comment: what have you tried so far? show us some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to paste below code in controller action that you are executing for copying quote and copy one quote with all product items into another.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
class Copyquote extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $quoteFactory;
    protected $formKey;
    protected $cart;
    protected $product;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        Cart $cart,
        ProductFactory $product
    ) {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->product = $product;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        try
        {
            $id = 'YOUR QUOTE ID';
            if ($id > 0) {
                $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($id);
                $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    $productId = $item->getProductId();
                    $_product = $this->product->create()->load($productId);

                    $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());

                    $info = $options['info_buyRequest'];
                    $request1 = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
                    $request1->setData($info);

                    $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $request1);
                }
                $this->cart->save();
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use or customize this code according to your need of copying one quote to another one in your Magento store

Comment: Thank you @Vishwas, I'll give that a try :)

Comment: Building on top of this, do you know which would be the best way to get it to save the quote with a new ID please, so that it's a new quote but has it's own ID?

Comment: it should automatically create new quote when adding products to cart , you can get current quote sequence from sequence profile table for your current store and build upon it

Comment: Hm, no it doesn't seem to create a new quote if I add products to the cart and update.

Comment: Ok, I think I nearly have this working now. Thanks again for your  code suggestion @vishwas I was half asleep yesterday and must have been looking at the code different. Your suggestion works well. I have added a little to it in order to meet the requirements for my task.

Upto now, I have managed to get it creating a new quote based upon the original one but then if I update the cart on the original quote, it seems to update the new quote instead :(

Comment: I have updated the original question above with the lastest updates :)

Comment: Check the data behaviour in quote table , you will have idea what are you doing worng . maybe $this->cart->setQuote($quote); this is culprit as it is setting the the new quote id to cart . But you need to check the qoute row in DB . you wil have the idea

Comment: I will take a look at this now. Thank you again for your help :)

Comment: Ok, I think I see the problem now but not sure why it's happening. 
Basically the plugin allows the user to share their basket via email. When the share button is clicked, a new quote is created with the original quote items. When the link in the email is clicked, it will call up the new quote.

Now, what happens at the minute is, if I have the original quote window open and then click the link in the email, this will load the new quote as expected; but if I start adding in items on the original quote and update the basket, the new quotes' basket is updated instead of the original one  :/

Comment: Aha, of course! This is because multiple tabs will be using the session on the same computer isn't it? Everything works as expected when I open the different quotes in incognito tabs. Thanks again for your help with this. Time for me to click that grey tick button above :D